# creating a dummy payment gateway using paypal

Tags: jakarta-ee, paypal, payment-gateway, dummy-data

[image: sreenshot]

I want to make a dummy payment gateway to test my project. I got to know about the paypal sandbox account through google.
And about creating buyer/seller accounts for testing.But couldn't find any option to create a developer account. The screenshots I have incuded are from different signup pages I came accoss.
But all of them require a compulsary state, city, ZIP code and phone no.
And since i am a non-US user to the form doesn't has my city listed.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I am aware you can use your normal PayPal account to Log into the https://developer.paypal.com you can then set-up you different types of accounts (or I suppose you could signup for another one with your same details).

I do know of another link for setting up sandbox accounts https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_login-submit Go there and click Sign up for free and you will be able to signup for different account for different country. Please note though this is on there sandbox site so perseverance is sometimes necessary as it may time-out.

There is one more option, but it is naughty. If you have found the American development signup and it is just for testing. You could always Google american details that will pass the basic checks and mix and match a made up address, although I do not advise you do this.

Comment: thanks for the answer +1 for that.. but the page is also asking for the credit/debit card details. I don't think I will need to make any real purchases while using sandbox.